# Can we always use WebClient in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

Currently we are using Webclient in a project. I get that Webclient is more of a asynchronous approach. Can we always use Webclient even incases where we need to use HttpClient in synchronous cases ? 
What would best approach ? Having both HttpClient and Webclient side by side and use them based on the case or can we always use Webclient as a project convention ?

Comment: You can use WebClient for blocking as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use `Webclient` in synchronous case. So better stick to one client for all cases for code consistency. I quote the remark from the `RestTemplate` 's [`javadoc`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) as below to address your concern :

> Please, consider using the
> org.springframework.web.reactive.client.WebClient which has a **more
> modern** API and supports **sync**, async, and streaming scenarios.